# cross domain ajax file upload

Tags: file-upload, drag-and-drop

I am using Valums Ajax Uploader (valums.com/ajax-upload) to upload files to a server. It works very well when the requesting URL and serving URL (ajax URL) are on same server but is not working when they are on different server.

Can someone please guide me about the same ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a late post but hope it helps.

In your server-side (e.g php), add header defined like this:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Content-type: application/json');
if(array_key_exists('HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS', $_SERVER)) {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']);
} else {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
}

if("OPTIONS" == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    exit(0);
}
```